# Why won't Xcode 5 let me specify iPad images for an iPhone app? And what about the iTunes Artwork icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7

Xcode 5 tries to be smart about what icons my app needs.

I have a non-universal iOS 7 app. Xcode only lets me specify icons for the iPhone, but none for iPad. Previously you could still add iPad-specific icons so it looks better on iPad.

Also Xcode doesn't list the 512x512 and 1024x1024 "iTunes Artwork" icons which are still a requirement according to iTunes Connect Developer Guide / iOS 7 HIG.

[image]

[image]

Like you can see in the above screenshots only 3 Xcode lets me specify only 3 icon files.

Where can I specify the big iTunes Artwork icon if not in the icons asset catalog?

Comment: Looks like you haven't told Xcode you are targeting the iPad...

Answer (score 13):

In your assets file (usually `Images.xcassets` / `Assets.xcassets`) go to the Attributes inspector on the right sidebar. Make sure iPad is ticked:

[image]

In later versions of Xcode, instead ensure an iOS (not "None") is selected on the iPad dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the AppIcon inside the asset catalog and bring up the properties navigator. In there you can add iPad assets for both iOS7 and pre-iOS7 and also specify whether the icons are pre-rendered or not.